# visual studio Find/Replace reuse group

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace

I have a regular expression for the Find and Replace window in Visual Studio (2008), where I have a tagged group (`{}`). And now I need to reuse that same group later in the statement again. In the replace box you can use the `\n` (where `n` is a number from 1 to 9), but in the find box you can't...

The tagged group is variable and contains expressions.

*Example*:

```
<{(:a*\:)*:a*}\>blablabla<\/{(:a*\:)*:a*}\>
```

The second `{(:a*\:)*:a*}` should only match the **same** match as the first one. So if a match with `asp:Label` in the first group succeeds, the second should only match when with it finds `asp:Label` again.

Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging up an old post!

Ive recently come up against this, it is possible.. its probably not an issue any more but this should work

```
\<{(:a.*\:).*:a*}\>.*\<\/\1\>
```

Comment: Aldo this does work on VS2010, I'm not convinced it does on VS2008. I'll check this Monday at work.